# Uncaught ReferenceError: WEBGL is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

In my HTML, following code portion

```
if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable()==false) {
    document.body.appendChild(WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage());
}
```

generates following error on console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WEBGL is not defined

I am already importing all necessary js, so the question is: how do you solve this?

Comment: You say I'm importing all necessary js. Can you show us?

Comment: And what HTML are you trying to apply this to?

Comment: What makes you think that `WEBGL` should be defined? Have you tried looking at the WebGL tutorial on MDN?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're using three.js library.

As the docs mention:

> Add
>   https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/WebGL.js
>   to your javascript and run the following before attempting to render
>   anything.

```
if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {

    // Initiate function or other initializations here
    animate();

} else {

    var warning = WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( warning );

}
```

So I don't think you actually loaded the required script.

Source: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/WebGL-compatibility-check

Comment: Thanks a lot Trace, it now complains about Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response and can not import the js

Comment: You can just download the three.js bundle and add it to you html page?